# How can I use missRanger to imputer missing integer values?

Tags: r, imputation

I am learning about imputation by trying to use R and missRanger to impute missing variables that must be integers. However, I get the following error:

```
## Error: Assigned data `if (...) NULL` must be compatible with existing data.
## i Error occurred for column `beds`.
## x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
## * Locations: 1, 2.
```

It seems to be that I cannot impute integer values, but I can if I make them decimal first.

Here is a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(missRanger)

# Here is a sample of the data
reprex_df

## # A tibble: 9 x 5
##    beds baths garages  price property_type
##   <int> <int>   <int>  <int> <chr>        
## 1    NA    NA      NA 770000 house        
## 2     2     1       0 300000 apartment    
## 3     2     2       2 735000 apartment    
## 4    NA    NA      NA 550000 apartment    
## 5     4     2       3 500000 house        
## 6     2     1       0 400000 apartment    
## 7     4     2       2 607000 house        
## 8     3     2       2 590000 house        
## 9     4     1       2 710000 house

# Try to impute missing bedrooms
imputed <- reprex_df %>% 
  missRanger()

## 
## Missing value imputation by random forests
## 
##   Variables to impute:       beds, baths, garages
##   Variables used to impute:  beds, baths, garages, price, property_type
## iter 1:  

## Error: Assigned data `if (...) NULL` must be compatible with existing data.
## i Error occurred for column `beds`.
## x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
## * Locations: 1, 2.

# Convert integers to numerics and try again
imputed2 <- reprex_df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer,
            as.numeric) %>% 
  missRanger()

## 
## Missing value imputation by random forests
## 
##   Variables to impute:       beds, baths, garages
##   Variables used to impute:  beds, baths, garages, price, property_type
## iter 1:  ...
## iter 2:  ...
## iter 3:  ...
## iter 4:  ...
## iter 5:  ...

# That works, but decimal rooms don't make sense
imputed2

## # A tibble: 9 x 5
##    beds baths garages  price property_type
##   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>        
## 1  3.44  1.86    2.15 770000 house        
## 2  2     1       0    300000 apartment    
## 3  2     2       2    735000 apartment    
## 4  2.77  1.83    1.84 550000 apartment    
## 5  4     2       3    500000 house        
## 6  2     1       0    400000 apartment    
## 7  4     2       2    607000 house        
## 8  3     2       2    590000 house        
## 9  4     1       2    710000 house
```

How can I impute missing integers using missRanger?

Comment: Can't you just `round` the output? `imputed2 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round)`

Answer (score 2):

Calling a dataset "reprex" does not make the example reproducible...

Since `missRanger` cannot change the way how a tibble internally reacts on type casting, here two suggestions:

1. Convert the tibble to a data.frame before calling missRanger **or** (and this is my favourite)
2. use the argument `pmm.k` to use predictive mean matching between the iterations. This has the nice side effect of filling gaps by realistic values. Integers will stay integers etc.

The vignette of `missRanger` explains these concepts, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missRanger/index.html

Disclaimer: I am the package maintainer of `missRanger`.

```
library(missRanger)
library(tidyverse)

# Example data
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.integer(cyl)) %>% 
  generateNA()

missRanger(mtcars2, pmm.k = 3, seed = 153)

# Gives
# # A tibble: 32 x 11
# mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  21       6  160    105  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     2
```